# direct url to server ip address and port

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8

We have a Windows 2012 dedicated server. There’s a custom service running on port xxxxx which accepts connections from our custom built hardware devices over TCP/IP port.  As of now we use servername.serverdomain.com:xxxxx to connect to the service and start communication. However, we prefer to use URL instead of server’s name or IP Address. So we got a custom url and set its name servers to point to dedicated server.  However, just setting DNS doesn’t seem to be working. Could someone please guide as to how to get it working?

UPDATE
In short I want www.custom-url.com being forwarded to servername.serverdomain.com:xxxxx. These requests are coming from hardware and not browser.

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve...You mean you want to use DNS to use port 80 instead of port xxxx ? DNS don't do that

Comment: No I want requests coming on e.g. www.custom-url.com forwarded to the service running on dedicated server port xxxxx. These connection requests are from hardware devices and not browser.

Comment: So you need a Reverse Proxy or a Firewall to NAT www.custom-url.com to dedicated-server:xxxx. Once again, DNS don't do that

Answer (score 3):

You could install, or use a preexisting, webserver to host your domain, and have a ProxyPass to your service.

I.e.

```
ProxyPass / serviceip:port
ProxyPassReverse / serviceip:port
```

Since you are mapping the root url you might want to put that config inside a virtualhost directive inside the webserver, at least if you share the webserver.

A rule with mod_rewrite, also inside a webserver,  can also help you.

The webserver can be hosted on a different, or the same, server.

Answer (score 1):

DNS won't do what you want.

You will need a Reverse Proxy or a Firewall to NAT

`www.custom-url.com` to `dedicated-server:xxxx`.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Setup a Firewall or a Reverse Proxy

Comment: I have an inbound firewall rule set up for this service.

Comment: So show us the config of this. Where is located your FW ?

Comment: It's located in Windows Firewall->Advanced Settings->Inbound Rules.

Comment: On `www.custom-url.com` server ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16630/discussion-between-am0-and-krisfr).